# Get first value TreeMultiMap

Tags: java, guava, treemap

im new in GUAVA, and i dont know how to get the first value in my TreeMultiMap order by a personal comparator.

I create a multitreemap like this:

```
TreeMultimap<String, ClassX> tm = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural(), new    ComparadorX();
```

I want to get the first value, not order by key, instead for Value.
I read the Javadoc, and says that i have to use Get(Key), but i dont know how to get my first key order by value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `TreeMultimap` itself is ordered by keys. *Each entry* in the map is ordered by values. It doesn't really make much sense to order the map overall by values, as each entry has multiple values... and it also reverses the normal meaning of "key" and "value", to be honest.

It's not clear what the bigger picture here is - what are you really trying to do? What data do you have? It's possible you could still use `TreeMultimap` just by inverting your concept of key and value, but it's hard to say for sure without more information.

Comment: My TreeMultiMap is like <URL,CLASS> and class have an attribute 'ranking', so i wanna to ask if in the TreeMultiMap exist the URL, and i want to use the TreeMultiMap order by Value like an a PriorityQueue, where i can get the first value(Like a Head) with the Highest ranking.

Comment: @user815672: It sounds like you should have two TreeMultiMaps - one from URL to CLASS, and the other from CLASS to URL. The second could potentially just be a `TreeSet` instead, unless you need to map each CLASS to whichever URLs produced it.

Comment: Thank you... i just want a TreeMap, where i can use a comparator for values. Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: @user815672: `TreeMap` simply doesn't do that. It's ordered by *keys*, as documented. As I say, a `TreeMultimap` swapping keys and values should work fine for you.